# Java openInputFile method doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, file, input, io

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner userScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileScanner = openInputFile();
        if (fileScanner == null)
            return;
        fileScanner.nextLine();
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            //handle input
        }
        fileScanner.close();
    }

    public static Scanner openInputFile() {
        String filename;
        Scanner scanner = null;
        System.out.print("Enter the input filename: ");
        filename = userScanner.nextLine();
        File file = new File(filename);
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } // end try
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("Can't open input file\n");
            return null; // array of 0 elements
        } // end catch
        return scanner;
    } // end openInputFile
}
```

I'm trying to open an input file using the following method but it prints "Can't open input file" every time. I double checked the spelling, the file is in the same directory. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Provide a directory listing of your file(s) so we can verify the spelling.  Add a line to print `file.getAbsolutePath()` as well as a line to print `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and show us the output from a run of the program.

Comment: This is the output when adding those 2 lines:

Comment: Enter the input filename: input.txt
C:\...\HW1\input.txt
C:\...\HW1
Can't open input file

Comment: Nevermind that helped me solved the problem haha thanks so much for your help. Now I'll know how to debug for next time :)